# Howto execute bootstrap modal from link within an email?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a web page called 'http://example.com/index.html' where I declared this link to call a bootstrap modal:

```
<a href="modal_content.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">My Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I call the 'http://example.com/index.html' with opened modal '#myModal' **with content** of **modal_content.html** from an email link? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add an `id` to your `<a>` tag so we can "click" it later:

```
<a id="clickMe" ...
```

Then, pass a `GET` parameter in the link from the email:

```
http://example.com/index.html?show_modal=true
```

And have your JS check for it:

```
if (location.search.indexOf('show_modal=true') > 0)
    $('#clickMe').click();
```

Comment: @udgru Please see my edits, now we're simulating a "click" instead of opening the modal directly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The click works fine for me and hopefully for other users here, too.